# how to catch fatal exceptions in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following exception thrown from android(or it can be thrown from ios, it doesn't matter) and I can't catch it to avoid app crash. Is there a solution to do it?

```
  > [ +276 ms] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2 [       
    > ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658): Process: com.example.myonpu, PID: 9658 [   
    > ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):
    > com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException:
    > Connection is not available to refresh token [        ]
    > E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):  at
    > com.microsoft.identity.client.internal.controllers.MsalExceptionAdapter.msalExceptionFromBaseException(MsalExceptionAdapter.java:49)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication$9.onError(PublicClientApplication.java:1621)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.ApiDispatcher$4$1.run(ApiDispatcher.java:424)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) [        ]
    > E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):  at
    > android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) [        ]
    > E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) [
    > ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):    at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) [        ]
    > E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
    > Method) [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) [       
    > ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658): Caused by:
    > com.microsoft.identity.common.exception.ClientException: Connection is
    > not available to refresh token [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):    at
    > com.microsoft.identity.common.adal.internal.net.HttpWebRequest.throwIfNetworkNotAvailable(HttpWebRequest.java:201)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.BaseController.performSilentTokenRequest(BaseController.java:328)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.BaseController.renewAccessToken(BaseController.java:204)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > com.microsoft.identity.client.internal.controllers.LocalMSALController.acquireTokenSilent(LocalMSALController.java:252)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.TokenCommand.execute(TokenCommand.java:89)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.ApiDispatcher$4.run(ApiDispatcher.java:401)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    > [        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 9658):   at
    > java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I need not to catch namely this exception, but to catch "fatal exceptions" like this. I tried try/catch and catchError for Future and nothing can do it.

Also tried FlutterError.onError this way:

```
mymethod() async{
  await methodWhichCanThrowException();
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
  };
  ...
}
```

if it can help here is msal_flutter package https://github.com/moodio/msal-flutter which I use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default method `catchError()` of `flutter`

```
mymethod() async{
  await methodWhichCanThrowException().catchError((e)=> print(e.toString());
  ...
}
```

Comment: as I mentioned I tried it, it doesn't work and as I get it catching this kind of error is impossible. all that I can do is to fork plugin and to pass error from platform to flutter like this: result.error("ERROR_TYPE","Error message",exceptionFromAuthentificationCallback.localizedMessage)

Comment: @IlyaMaximencko did you solve the problem when using this msal_flutter package. I am also having issues on Android while on iOS I did manage to make it work.

Comment: @Anand check my fork, hope it can solve your issue https://github.com/IlyaMax/msal-flutter